# differentiate between chrome browser and chrome app in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, user-agent

How do I differentiate between if my code is running inside a chrome browser or a chrome app ? The application uses webview to load specific pages in which the javascript code has to work differently for chrome app and chrome browser.

Comment: @Xan This is not a duplicate. This is about code inside a webview.

Comment: Right, sorry, itchy trigger finger. I'll undupe.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to [inject a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-addContentScripts) into the webview that, in turn, [injects some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) into the page before it loads.

Something along those lines:

```
webview.addContentScripts([{
  name: 'beacon',
  matches: ['https://www.example.com/*'],
  js: { files: ['beacon.js'] },
  run_at: 'document_start'
}]);
webview.src = "https://www.example.com/app"

// beacon.js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "window.inWebview = true;";
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

Then, in your code, you can check whether `window.inWebview` is defined and true.

Less clean alternatives:

- Modify the user-agent in a predictable way with [`webview.setUserAgentOverride`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride).
- Simply load the page with an extra parameter: `https://www.example.com/app?webview=1`.